# is it possible to deactive twig cache for a single theme custom template?

Tags: theming, caching

i am having a custom template for rendering a medialink url from a paragraph media entity ref field.
In production with twig cache activated, modifiying the media attached file , does not update the content making reference to that media, unless the render cache is emptied.

paragraph--link-media.html.twig

```
{% set classes = [
  'paragraph',
  'paragraph-link-media',
] %}
{% set link_classes = [] %}
{% set aria_label = "" %}
{% set aria_describedby = "" %}
{% if content.field_aria_title|field_value %}
  {% set aria_label =  content.field_aria_title|field_value|render %}
{% endif %}
{% if content.field_link_description|field_value %}
  {% set aria_describedby = "link-description-"~paragraph.id() %}
{% endif %}
{% if content.field_link_style|field_value %}
  {% set link_classes = link_classes|merge(['cta-link']) %}
  {% set classes = classes|merge([content.field_link_style.0["#options"].entity.field_class_name.value]) %}
{% endif %}
{% if content.field_link_extra_styles|field_value %}
  {% for extra_style in content.field_link_extra_styles|field_value %}
    {% set classes = classes|merge([extra_style["#options"].entity.field_class_name.value]) %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if content.field_link_fa_style|field_value %}
  {% set classes = classes|merge(['link-fa']) %}
{% endif %}
{% block paragraph %}
  {% block content %}
    {% if content.field_link_style|field_value %}
      {% if content.field_cta_align|field_value %}
        {% set class_cta_align = content.field_cta_align|field_value %}
      {% else %}
        {% set class_cta_align = "cta-center" %}
      {% endif %}
      <div class="{{ class_cta_align }}">
    {% endif %}
    <span{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
      {% set attributes_link = create_attribute() %}
      {% if aria_label != "" and content.field_link_description|field_value and not content.field_link_style|field_value %}
        {% set attributes_link = attributes_link.setAttribute('aria-label', aria_label).setAttribute('aria-describedby', aria_describedby) %}
      {% elseif content.field_link_description|field_value and not content.field_link_style|field_value %}
        {% set attributes_link = attributes_link.setAttribute('aria-describedby', aria_describedby) %}
      {% elseif aria_label != "" %}
        {% set attributes_link = attributes_link.setAttribute('aria-label',aria_label) %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if link_media.url|length>0 %}
        <a {{ attributes_link.addClass(link_classes) }} href="{{ link_media.url }}">
      {% endif %}
      {% if content.field_link_fa_style|field_value %}
        {{ content.field_link_fa_style.0["#options"].entity.field_fa_code.value|raw }}
      {% endif %}
```

How can i fix that ?

The auto_reload: true does not seem to be recommended in production and specific conf to a theme does not seem to be possible
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2002606

Comment: You need to make sure your paragraph display has the media's (and/or media file's) cache tag so that its render cache is invalidated when the media or media file is updated.

Comment: @sonfd how do u do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any entity template (like `node.html.twig` or `paragraph.html.twig`, but not `field.html.twig`), you *must* render `{{ content }}` at least once, otherwise the cache tags to not bubble up. A `{{ content.field_something }}` is not enough. You'll notice this problem everytime you need to render a nested entity (e.g. a media entity inside a paragraph or a node.)

If your design does not allow a blanket `{{ content }}`, do somehing like `{% set dummy_force_cache_bubbling = content|render %}`. This doesn't render anything visually, but it triggers the cache processing.

Comment: i would not have find it without u :)